# How can I fill a matrix using a fortran subroutine (or function) and pass the matrix back to the main program?

Tags: function, matrix, fortran, subroutine

I'm working on a Fortran 90 assignment, and I'm having a lot of issues learning how to use subroutines and functions, and I'm hoping someone can help me.  if it isn't obvious, I'm extremely new to FORTRAN and much more comfortable with language like C and Java.

Anyway, here's what I have to do:  The user selects what they would like to do: add, subtract, multiply, or transpose two matrices.  I'm using a select case for this, which works great.  However, I obviously don't want to duplicate the same code to fill two matrices four different times, so I'm trying to make it a separate function.  Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
integer matrix1(11,11), matrix2(11,11)
integer rows1,cols1,rows2,cols2,i,j
case (1)  
    matrix1 = fillmatrix(rows1,cols1)
    matrix2 = fillmatrix(rows2,cols2)
.
.
.


function fillmatrix(rows,columns)
  integer input
  read *,rows,columns
  do i = 1, rows
    do j = 1, columns
       fillmatrix(i,j) = read *,input
    end do
  end do
end
```

Is there any way to do something like this?  And am i making myself clear, because sometimes I have trouble saying what I mean.

Or is this possible?

```
matrix1 = fillmatrix(rows1)cols1)


function fillmatrix(rows,columns)
   integer input,matrix(11,11)
       //fill matrix
   return matrix
end
```

Comment: Are you restricted to FORTRAN 77, or could you use newer Standards? Starting with Fortran 90 you can have functions that return arrays.

Comment: Umm, the assignment document doesn't say we HAVE to use f77, so I could probably use f90, but I haven't done anything with fortran 90 at all, so I don't know what else I'd need to change

Comment: Oh I just noticed... `select case` IS Fortran 90 ;-) See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran)

Comment: Whoa.  I had no idea what select case was Fortran 90...  Shows how much I pay attention.  I'm obviously writing sloppy code if I am getting them confused that badly, haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C or Java, you just have functions, but Fortran has both functions and subroutines.  In a case like this, it might be easier to write it as a `subroutine` instead of as a `function`, so your call would look something like

```
integer matrix1(11,11), matrix2(11,11)
integer rows1,cols1,rows2,cols2,i,j
...
case (1)  
    call fillmatrix(matrix1)
    call fillmatrix(matrix2)
...
```

where the subroutine would look something like

```
subroutine fillmatrix(m)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(out) :: m(:,:)

    integer :: i, j
    do j = 1,size(m,2)
        do i = 1,size(m,1)
            read *, m(i,j)
        end do
    end do
end subroutine fillmatrix
```

Note that I'm not directly specifying the array bounds - instead I'm figuring them out inside the subroutine.  This means that this subroutine needs an explicit interface - the easiest way to get this is to put it in either a `contains` block or a `module`.

Comment: "In C or Java, you just have functions" - this isn't correct.  A FORTRAN function returns a value; a subroutine does not.  All C-based languages, including Java, have both too.  You can always return a value from a function.  I would say that a function with a void return is the equivalent of a subroutine.

Comment: @duffymo - I agree with you that a "function with a void return is the equivalent of a subroutine" insofar as that they have the same effect.  However, in C/Java/etc. there's still just a single "function" syntax whereas Fortran has completely different syntactical forms for the two things.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a `function`, you need to know the size of the matrix before calling it. Here is a small example:

```
module readMatrix
  implicit none
contains
  function fillmatrix(cols,rows)
    implicit none
    ! Argument/return value
    integer,intent(in)  :: rows,cols
    integer             :: fillmatrix(rows,cols)
    ! Loop counters
    integer             :: i,j

    do j = 1, rows
      do i = 1, cols
        write(*,*) 'Enter matrix element ',i,j
        read *,fillmatrix(i,j)
      enddo ! j
    enddo ! i
  end function
end module

program test
  use readMatrix
  implicit none
  integer,allocatable :: matrix(:,:)
  integer             :: row,col, stat

  write(*,*) 'Enter number of rows'
  read *,row
  write(*,*) 'Enter number of cols'
  read *,col
  allocate( matrix(col,row), stat=stat )
  if (stat/=0) stop 'Cannot allocate memory'

  matrix = fillmatrix(col,row)

  write(*,*) matrix
  deallocate(matrix)
end program
```

This is similar, using a `subroutine` and a static array (like in the question):

```
module readMatrix
  implicit none
contains
  subroutine fillmatrix(cols,rows,matrix)
    implicit none
    ! Argument/return value
    integer,intent(out) :: rows,cols
    integer,intent(out) :: matrix(:,:)
    ! Loop counters
    integer             :: i,j

    write(*,*) 'Enter number of rows, up to a maximum of ',size(matrix,2)
    read *,rows
    write(*,*) 'Enter number of cols, up to a maximum of ',size(matrix,1)
    read *,cols

    if ( rows > size(matrix,2) .or. cols > size(matrix,1) ) &
      stop 'Invalid dimension specified'

    do j = 1, rows
      do i = 1, cols
        write(*,*) 'Enter matrix element ',i,j
        read *,matrix(i,j)
      enddo ! j
    enddo ! i
  end subroutine
end module

program test
  use readMatrix
  implicit none
  integer,parameter   :: maxCol=10,maxRow=10
  integer             :: matrix(maxCol,maxRow)
  integer             :: row,col

  call fillmatrix(col,row,matrix)

  write(*,*) matrix(1:col,1:row)

end program
```

You could even pass an `allocatable` array to the subroutine and allocate it there, but that's a different story...

Comment: A little quibble - note that your first sentence isn't quite true with Fortran 90 - you don't necessarily need to know the length of the function result before you call a function, but it is rather messy (you need to use a function with a pointer result).  For your "different story" in your last sentence to be applicable, you are talking Fortran 2003, and then writing and using functions that return results not known until the function has started executing is easy - function results can be allocatable and you can use allocate-on-assignment at the point of reference.

Comment: Yeah, I know... But I didn't want to overload the poster. (Especially since the original premise was FORTRAN 77).